# SnmpV3 Trap Receiver with Authentication/Privacy - dynamically obtain engineID from agents

Tags: java, snmp

I am trying to develop an `SNMPv3` Trap Receiver using the WebNms AdventNet API.
If I use authentication and privacy options (`MD5 + DES`), I need to know the `engineID` of the Agent that sends the traps in
order to decrypt the trap content. How can I obtain this `engineID` dynamically (without hardcoding it in my application)?
[I saw that it's possible to perform a discovery of the `engineID`](https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/v3/configureuser.html)

But for this to work I need to provide the port used by the Agent when sends the traps (and the agent is a real network element which uses random source ports).

The following code is working, but I hard-coded the `engineID`.
Is there a different way to decrypt the traps without hardcoding the `engineID`?

```
public class DragosApp2 implements SnmpClient{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SnmpException {
        SnmpAPI api = new SnmpAPI();
        SnmpEngineEntry snmpEntry = new SnmpEngineEntry("10.10.66.79");
        SnmpEngineTable engineTable = api.getSnmpEngine();
        engineTable.addEntry(snmpEntry);
        SnmpSession session = new SnmpSession(api);
        session.addSnmpClient(new DragosApp2());
        UDPProtocolOptions ses_opt = new UDPProtocolOptions();
        ses_opt.setLocalPort(162);
        session.setProtocolOptions(ses_opt);
        session.open();
        byte[] engineID = gethexValue("0x80001f888026f9036957333c81");  // HOW can I replace this part??

        USMUserEntry user = new USMUserEntry(new String("dragos3").getBytes(), engineID);
        user.setAuthProtocol(USMUserEntry.MD5_AUTH);
        user.setPrivProtocol(USMUserEntry.CBC_DES);

        byte[] authKey = USMUtils.password_to_key(USMUserEntry.MD5_AUTH, 
                                                new String("12345678").getBytes(),
                                                new String("12345678").getBytes().length,
                                                engineID);

        byte[] privKey = USMUtils.password_to_key(USMUserEntry.MD5_AUTH,
                            new String("12345678").getBytes(),
                            new String("12345678").getBytes().length,
                            engineID,
                            USMUserEntry.CBC_DES);

        user.setAuthPassword(new String("12345678").getBytes());
        user.setPrivPassword(new String("12345678").getBytes());
        user.setAuthKey(authKey);
        user.setPrivKey(privKey);
        user.setSecurityLevel((byte)3);
        user.setEngineEntry(snmpEntry);
        USMUserTable uut = (USMUserTable)api.getSecurityProvider().getTable(3);
        uut.addEntry(user);
    }   
}
```